# Benchmarking "sample" function in R

Tags: r, random

I was benchmarking the `sample` function in R and comparing it with `igraph:sample_seq` and ran into a strange result.

When I run something like:

```
library(microbenchmark)
library(igraph)
set.seed(1234)
N <- 55^4
M <- 500
(mbm <- microbenchmark(v1 = {sample(N,M)}, 
                       v2 = {igraph::sample_seq(1,N,M)}, times=50))
```

I get a result like this:

```
Unit: microseconds
 expr       min        lq        mean     median        uq       max neval
   v1 21551.475 22655.996 26966.22166 23748.2555 28340.974 47566.237    50
   v2    32.873    37.952    82.85238    81.7675    96.141   358.277    50
```

But when I run, for example,

```
set.seed(1234)
N <- 100^4
M <- 500
(mbm <- microbenchmark(v1 = {sample(N,M)}, 
                      v2 = {igraph::sample_seq(1,N,M)}, times=50))
```

I get a much faster result for `sample`:

```
Unit: microseconds
 expr    min     lq     mean  median     uq     max neval
   v1 52.165 55.636 64.70412 58.2395 78.636  88.120    50
   v2 39.174 43.504 62.09600 53.5715 73.253 176.419    50
```

It seems that when `N` is a power of 10 (or some other special number?), `sample` is much faster than other smaller `N` that are not powers of 10. Is this expected behavior or am I missing something?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`sample()` or rather `sample.int()` by default uses a hash algorithm when certain conditions are met, one being that n > 1e7.

If the second benchmark is rerun without hashing you'll see that it is also much slower than than the igraph function.

```
set.seed(1234)
N2 <- 100^4
M <- 500
(mbm <- microbenchmark(v1 = {sample.int(N2,M, useHash = FALSE)}, 
                       v2 = {igraph::sample_seq(1,N2,M)}, times=50))

Unit: microseconds
 expr        min         lq         mean     median         uq       max neval cld
   v1 144297.936 150368.649 167224.95664 154283.077 157832.520 407710.78    50   b
   v2     61.218     65.392     92.35544     87.885    118.262    148.87    50  a
```

From the documentation for the `useHash` argument:

> logical indicating if the hash-version of the algorithm should be
>   used. Can only be used for replace = FALSE, prob = NULL, and size <=
>   n/2, and really should be used for large n, as useHash=FALSE will use
>   memory proportional to n.

Comment: Interesting! That seems to be it.

Comment: Now, I wonder if it is possible to compare how much memory the hashed "sample.int" uses versus igraph::sample_seq (?)